# Open Associated Files in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file

I am trying to associate multiple files with my app i have done associating files but when i try to open multiple files app open just one file, to open the file iam using this code in form load event

```
        For Each arg In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
            open_File(return_rtb, arg)
        Next arg
```

And the second problem is myApp is single instance app how to catch if user double click on a file while myApp is running like form load event for first time. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a built-in capability for VB.NET, provided by the application framework option, turned on by default for a Winforms app.  Project + Properties, Application tab, tick the "Make single instance application" option.

Use the My.Application.StartupNextInstance event.  The code snippet in the [MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9z4eyh8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for this event shows you how to use the e.CommandLine property to discover the path of the file passed to the second instance.

Comment: thanks i got the nextInstance but when i use this code in nextInstace it open previous file not new
        For Each arg In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
            open_File(return_rtb, arg)
        Next arg
any solution?

Comment: I cannot diagnose your code from that comment.  Use the debugger to find out what's going wrong.